# How to work with like operation in one to many realtionship in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I use like operator in one to ManyRealtion ship.Please check my code below for my Situation.

I have Org Class and DeptClass with One - Many Realtion ship

Org.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_STD_ORGANIZATION")
public class Organization implements Serializable  {
 @Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="FLD_ORG_ID")
private Long organizationId;

@Column(name="FLD_ORG_NAME")
private String orgName;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private java.util.List<Department> listOfDepartMents = new java.util.ArrayList<Department>();

//setter and getter methods
}
```

Dept.java

```
     @Entity
      @Table(name="TBL_STD_DEPARTMENT")
      public class Department implements Serializable { 

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "FLD_DEPARTMENT_ID")
private Long departmentId;

@Column(name = "FLD_DEPARTMENT_NAME")
private String departmentName;
   // Setter and getter methods
```

}

Now i have orgName but for deptName i have only first two characters(for like operator) based on this orgName I fire the query but i got number of Department Objects for the OrgName.I want to short those departmetns by using like how can i do this any one  help me..I am using HQL

Comment: Please add your HQL also to the question!

Comment: please refer to [this](http://www.stpe.se/2008/07/hibernate-hql-like-query-named-parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

You can find more about one to many relation from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_one_to_many_mapping.htm)